# Is it ALWAYS safe to assume that an HTTP packet with 'text/*' will NEVER have a '\0'?

Tags: c, http, network-programming, c-strings

I'm writing an embedded C program that communicates using HTTP. I've got it working, but I've not done much with networking before and just wanted to make sure that I'm not making any really bad assumptions.

Can I safely assume that any non-malicious HTTP packet that has a Content-Type of `text/<something>` will not have a zero in it? There are quite a few places in my code that rely in there only being the '\0' at the end of the string. I do have some protections in place that will always stop after the given Content-Length and will never overflow the buffer that I am writing into, but I'd like to make sure, as much as possible, that the low level stuff works because I won't be able to update those parts once these devices ship.

Also, can anyone point me towards any resources that have common gottchas in network programming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that’s not a safe assumption even if you can guarantee that the messages are conforming. For example, UTF-16 text will almost certainly contain NUL bytes.

Also, a poorly configured web server, of which there are plenty, might conceivably serve gzip data even if your client does not accept it.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not a safe assumption.

Always assume arbitrary input is maliciously malformed.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's definitely **not** safe to assume.

There is no way for you to know that the user is even using a web browser. An attacker could write an application which sends arbitrary data to your application which looks like it originates from a web browser, but then sends a nul character to crash your program (or even worse: exploit a buffer overflow).

**Never trust user data!**

Having a high security standard is especially important for embedded device programming, because the software on these devices is usually hard to update when a vulnerability is detected after they shipped.

Comment: I kinda figured that that would be the answer. In theory these devices should never get any unsolicited packets as they are on a cellular network and supposedly have their own NAT and they will only ever be making requests to our servers. The update-ability is the reason that we're doing as much as possible in Lua and I'm really trying to make sure that the stuff that needs to be c is as good as I ca make it.

Comment: And what about data corruption ... embedded device can be affected by EMI, solar radiation, etc.